# Using SIMD to find the biggest difference of two elements

Tags: algorithm, optimization, simd

I wrote an algorithm to get the biggest difference between two elements in an std::vector where the bigger of the two values must be at a higher index than the lower value.

```
    unsigned short int min = input.front();
    unsigned short res = 0;

    for (size_t i = 1; i < input.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (input[i] <= min)
        {
            min = input[i];
            continue;
        }

        int dif = input[i] - min;
        res = dif > res ? dif : res;
    }

    return res != 0 ? res : -1;
```

Is it possible to optimize this algorithm using SIMD? I'm new to SIMD and so far I've been unsuccessful with this one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't specify any particular architecture so I'll keep this mostly architecture neutral with an algorithm described in English.  But it requires a SIMD ISA that can efficiently branch on SIMD compare results to check a usually-true condition, like x86 but not really ARM NEON.

This won't work well for NEON because it doesn't have a movemask equivalent, and SIMD -> integer causes stalls on many ARM microarchitectures.

---

**The normal case while looping over the array is that an element, or a whole SIMD vector of elements, is *not* a new `min`, and not `diff` candidate**.  We can quickly fly through those elements, only slowing down to get the details right when there's a new `min`.  This is like a SIMD `strlen` or SIMD `memcmp`, except instead of stopping at the first search hit, we just go scalar for one block and then resume.

---

**For each vector `v[0..7]` of the input array** (assuming 8 `int16_t` elements per vector (16 bytes), but that's arbitrary):

- **SIMD compare `vmin > v[0..7]`, and check for any elements being true**.  (e.g. x86 `_mm_cmpgt_epi16` / `if(_mm_movemask_epi8(cmp) != 0)`)  **If there's a new `min` somewhere, we have a special case**: the old min applies to some elements, but the new min applies to others.  And it's possible there are multiple new-min updates within the vector, and new-diff candidates at any of those points.

  So handle this vector with scalar code (updating a scalar `diff` which doesn't need to be in sync with the vector `diffmax` because we don't need position).

  Broadcast the final `min` to `vmin` when you're done.  Or do a SIMD horizontal `min` so out-of-order execution of later SIMD iterations can get started without waiting for a `vmin` from scalar.  Should work well if the scalar code is branchless, so there are no mispredicts in the scalar code that cause later vector work to be thrown out.

  **As an alternative, a SIMD prefix-sum type of thing (actually prefix-min) could produce a `vmin` where every element is the min up to that point.**  ([parallel prefix (cumulative) sum with SSE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19494114/parallel-prefix-cumulative-sum-with-sse)).  You could *always* do this to avoid any branching, but if new-min candidates are rare then it's expensive.  Still, it could be viable on ARM NEON where branching is hard.
- If there's no new min, **SIMD packed max `diffmax[0..7] = max(diffmax[0..7], v[0..7]-vmin)`**.  (Use saturating subtraction so you don't get wrap-around to a large unsigned difference, if you're using unsigned max to handle the full range.)

At the end of the loop, do a SIMD horizontal max of the `diffmax` vector.  Notice that since we *don't* need the position of the max-difference, we don't need to update all elements inside the loop when one finds a new candidate.  We don't even need to keep the scalar special-case `diffmax` and SIMD `vdiffmax` in sync with each other, just check at the end to take the max of the scalar and SIMD max diffs.

---

SIMD min/max is basically the same as a horizontal sum, except you use packed-max instead of packed-add.  For x86, see [Fastest way to do horizontal float vector sum on x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996764/fastest-way-to-do-horizontal-float-vector-sum-on-x86/35270026#35270026).

Or on x86 with SSE4.1 for 16-bit integer elements, `phminposuw` / `_mm_minpos_epu16` can be used for min or max, signed or unsigned, with appropriate tweaks to the input.  `max = -min(-diffmax)`.  You can treat diffmax as unsigned because it's known to be non-negative, but  [Horizontal minimum and maximum using SSE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22256525/horizontal-minimum-and-maximum-using-sse/22268350#22268350) shows how to flip the sign bit to range-shift signed to unsigned and back.

---

We probably get a branch mispredict every time we find a new `min` candidate, or else we're finding new `min` candidates too often for this to be efficient.

If new `min` candidates are expected frequently, using shorter vectors could be good.  Or on discovering there's a new-`min` in a current vector, then use narrower vectors to only go scalar over fewer elements.  On x86, you might use `bsf` (bit-scan forward) to find which element had the first new-min.  That gives your scalar code a data dependency on the vector compare-mask, but if the branch to it was mispredicted then the compare-mask will be ready.  Otherwise if branch-prediction can somehow find a pattern in which vectors need the scalar fallback, prediction+speculative execution will break that data dependency.

---

Unfinished / broken (by me) example adapted from @harold's deleted answer of a fully branchless version that constructs a vector of min-up-to-that-element on the fly, for x86 SSE2.

(@harold wrote it with suffix-max instead of min, which is I think why he deleted it.  I partially converted it from max to min.)

A branchless intrinsics version for x86 could look *something* like this.  But branchy is probably better unless you expect some kind of slope or trend that makes new `min` values frequent.

```
// BROKEN, see FIXME comments.
// converted from @harold's suffix-max version

int broken_unfinished_maxDiffSSE(const std::vector<uint16_t> &input) {
    const uint16_t *ptr = input.data();

    // construct suffix-min
    // find max-diff at the same time
    __m128i min = _mm_set_epi32(-1);
    __m128i maxdiff = _mm_setzero_si128();

    size_t i = input.size();
    for (; i >= 8; i -= 8) {
        __m128i data = _mm_loadu_si128((const __m128i*)(ptr + i - 8));

   // FIXME: need to shift in 0xFFFF, not 0, for min.
   // or keep the old data, maybe with _mm_alignr_epi8
        __m128i d = data;
        // link with suffix
        d = _mm_min_epu16(d, _mm_slli_si128(max, 14));
        // do suffix-min within block.
        d = _mm_min_epu16(d, _mm_srli_si128(d, 2));
        d = _mm_min_epu16(d, _mm_shuffle_epi32(d, 0xFA));
        d = _mm_min_epu16(d, _mm_shuffle_epi32(d, 0xEE));
        max = d;

        // update max-diff
        __m128i diff = _mm_subs_epu16(data, min);  // with saturation to 0
        maxdiff = _mm_max_epu16(maxdiff, diff);
    }

    // horizontal max
    maxdiff = _mm_max_epu16(maxdiff, _mm_srli_si128(maxdiff, 2));
    maxdiff = _mm_max_epu16(maxdiff, _mm_shuffle_epi32(maxdiff, 0xFA));
    maxdiff = _mm_max_epu16(maxdiff, _mm_shuffle_epi32(maxdiff, 0xEE));
    int res = _mm_cvtsi128_si32(maxdiff) & 0xFFFF;

    unsigned scalarmin = _mm_extract_epi16(min, 7);  // last element of last vector
    for (; i != 0; i--) {
        scalarmin = std::min(scalarmin, ptr[i - 1]);
        res = std::max(res, ptr[i - 1] - scalarmin);
    }

    return res != 0 ? res : -1;
}
```

We could replace the scalar cleanup with a final unaligned vector, if we handle the overlap between the last full vector `min`.

Comment: That way I did that "link with suffix" step that got broken by switching to `min` was a bad approach anyway, really should a broadcast and then putting it in *after* the in-block stuff to make the loop carried dependency faster

Comment: @harold: oh good point!  This doesn't even bottleneck on shuffles, but rather on the shuffle->max->...  dep chain.  I wanted to include some kind of code as an example of what intrinsics look like, for the OP to google more about.  So I'm going to leave that not-great code block there with warning comments.  If you get around to improving/fixing it, feel free to edit my answer, or better undelete your own.