# Looking for an efficient function to find an index of max element in SIMD vector using a library

Tags: c++, optimization, simd, avx, vector-class-library

There are similar older questions, but they are using intrinsics and old instruction sets. I have a function `f` written with C++ vector class library (https://www.agner.org/optimize/#vectorclass):

```
int f(const Vec32uc &a) {
  Vec32uc b{horizontal_max(a)};
  return horizontal_find_first(a == b);
}
```

and compiled on https://godbolt.org/z/Gfjo7zo1c with `-O3 -march=alderlake`. The result looks a bit long:

```
f(Vec32uc const&):
        vmovdqa ymm1, YMMWORD PTR [rdi]
        vextracti128    xmm0, ymm1, 0x1
        vpmaxub xmm2, xmm1, xmm0
        vpunpckhqdq     xmm0, xmm2, xmm2
        vpmaxub xmm0, xmm0, xmm2
        vpsrldq xmm2, xmm0, 4
        vpmaxub xmm0, xmm0, xmm2
        vpsrldq xmm2, xmm0, 2
        vpmaxub xmm0, xmm0, xmm2
        vpsrldq xmm2, xmm0, 1
        vpmaxub xmm0, xmm0, xmm2
        vpbroadcastb    ymm0, xmm0
        vpcmpeqb        ymm1, ymm1, ymm0
        vpmovmskb       eax, ymm1
        test    eax, eax
        je      .L3
        bsfl eax, eax
.L1:
        vzeroupper
        ret
.L3:
        mov     eax, -1
        jmp     .L1
```

compared to intrinsic solutions, e.g. [Find index of maximum element in x86 SIMD vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23590610/find-index-of-maximum-element-in-x86-simd-vector), but I may be wrong. Is there a more efficient implementation using a SIMD library and modern X86-64 instruction set.

Comment: The answer that you linked computes the maximum of 32 bit integers. That needs 3 shuffles and 3 `max` call (`2**3 == 8 ints == 32 byte`). You compute for 8 bit ints. That needs 5 shuffles and `max` calls (`2**5 == 32 byte`). That's what you see in the assembly. I don't see any particular inefficiencies. Which part do you think is superfluous or inefficient?

Comment: Perhaps shuffle pairs together and mask (to zero-extend the max of the pair to 16-bit) for `phminposuw`?  It only exists in a 128-bit form, but you could use it and broadcast the result to find it position in the original vector.  But it's a min, so you'd need a 1:1 mapping that makes the largest unsigned element into the smallest.  I think subtract-from-0 does that.

Comment: @PeterCordes subtract-from-0 leaves 0 as 0 so it doesn't quite reverse the whole number line, xor-with-all-ones does though

Comment: @harold Since we need to extend to 16 bit anyway, `USHORT_MAX - x` should work, right? Something like this: https://godbolt.org/z/ExnMc9rfc But if I understand OP correctly, he wants a library solution rather than intrinsics. I'm not aware of such as thing and SO doesn't permit that type of question anyway

Comment: @Homer512 `USHORT_MAX - x` works, it's equivalent to `x ^ USHORT_MAX` too .. apparently GCC knows that

Comment: @Homer512 "I don't see any particular inefficiencies". I will go with your opinion. I don't have in depth x86-64 SIMD instructions knowledge.

Comment: Updated my answer with chtz's idea, and with a couple mentions of Gracemont tuning.

Answer (score 3):

[SSE4.1 `phminposuw`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/phminposuw) is a horizontal min of 8x 16-bit elements.    8 elements otherwise takes 3 shuffle/min steps, 6 instructions, so **if we can use fewer uops than that to massage our data into an input for `_mm_minpos_epu16`**, we come out ahead.  It's single-uop with 3 to 4 cycle latency across Zen / Skylake / Gracemont, so it's also a latency win vs. 6 shuffle/min ops.  (https://uops.info/)

It's not available for wider vectors even with AVX-512, so we do need two reduction steps to get our 32 elements down to 8, but we can get them zero-extended to 16-bit for free by being clever about it.  (It does also find the position of the min, but only on our already-reduced input which isn't useful here.)

Bitwise NOT turns UINT8_MIN (`0`) into UINT8_MAX (`255`) and vice versa.  It's the same thing as  `255-x` which more obviously does what we want, a 1:1 transform that reverses an unsigned `<=` compare, without wrapping for any `uint8_t` value.  (Thanks to @harold and @Homer512 in comments for fixing my initial idea.)

@chtz had a good idea: unpack the data with indices, so the index is part of the max or min u16 element we find, skipping the broadcast/compare/movemask/bit-scan.  This is orthogonal to using phminpos, and works for any ISA and element-size as long as we have a vertical min or max for elements that are twice as wide.  The first reduction step changes to doing something to *both* inputs, widening elements, instead of just shuffling the high half down to the bottom.  The biggest benefit is critical path latency, but this does also help throughput slightly.

In case of a tie, when the original 8-bit value is equal, the low half, the index, will be the tie-break.  If you want the first occurrence of the max element, min with inverted elements and normal indices works: the smaller index will be the min.  Or max with normal elements and inverted indices, which you flip after some reduction.

```
#include "vectorclass.h"

int maxpos_u8_noscan_unpack(const Vec32uc v)
{
    Vec32uc indices = _mm256_setr_epi8( ~0, ~1, ~2, ~3, ~4, ~5, ~6, ~7,
                                        ~8, ~9,~10,~11,~12,~13,~14,~15,
                                       ~16,~17,~18,~19,~20,~21,~22,~23,
                                       ~24,~25,~26,~27,~28,~29,~30,~31);
    __m256i lo = _mm256_unpacklo_epi8(indices, v);  // pair value:index in a u16 with value most significant
    __m256i hi = _mm256_unpackhi_epi8(indices, v);  // then find the max of those u16 elements and extract the payload
    Vec16us vu16 = _mm256_max_epu16(lo, hi);
    Vec8us vu8 = max(vu16.get_low(), vu16.get_high());  // narrow to 128-bit
// on a tie, we take the max ~index or min index = first occurence of max

    // inverted indices allow XOR with set1(-1), a cheaper constant to generate than set1_epi16(0xff00)
    auto vinv = ~vu8;   // 1:1 mapping that flips max to min, same as 255-v (for bytes)
 // Now we're looking for the min u16, whose low 8 bits are the index of the original u8
    __m128i minpos = _mm_minpos_epu16(vinv);  // min value in the bottom u16 of the vector
    unsigned min = _mm_cvtsi128_si32(minpos);
    return (uint8_t)min;                      // movd + scalar movzx is cheaper than  pextrb 0
  // a smarter compiler would vmovd into a different reg like EDX, allowing mov-elimination for the movzx
}
```

[**Godbolt**](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIABwAbKSuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEIACcwQAOqAqETgwe3r4BaRlZAuGRMSzxiSm2mPaOAkIETMQEuT5%2BQTV12Y3NBKXRcQnJwQpNLW35nWN9A%2BWVIwCUtqhexMjsHOYAzBHI3lgA1OZmAG6YDiT7TAoKAHQIJyYaAIIzjsiHEbQRmM8vEQIhxYTFU6QUAH0vP4IQwMqIGFCGKkmMgANYQNAMMaHABqF22Zi8n1Oi3%2BJgA7FZXodaXiCUTPhF8BsFMdtgARQ4QlgsMwAVkCEKUBGIEMwqTw/gghwAfhpSHKuIrZWYVdsVdI5fyVcE5RTSP86caTaazeazbL/CqkqRZVwFfblfa1faNfbpPadUaLb6/eb7cF7Qb7db7bbVY6zM6zK6zBqff6k/7VZ6BXazEGzCGzGGzBHto7tlwydtqS9jRCeQLAnhDrRUOyuTy%2BYKkSj0Q3xZLpcy8KzFaSTGXaQB6UeHFF4YiHU5iLzsZmYVRfBiHJiHLxcQKHADuhAQs/nmGBGSBmWADDwNARBET3OrgrrCDrw%2BbvJr7dRaJf3alED7AdZ1LCwxwnAgEEYQ4aAYdBDggk8QRXVAqHghAMhPLcd1qTA2EENlDDg5dRVRIEEMnJgAE8GyYdB73xZBty8NlTiwptuQ/NskO7LCIAbRUXxA%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%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%2BqSPcL56CQ1vh2NEj9DzCI9nCMyHlobE3hojc6/Bx6%2BXRjhPCd5GbCUYoEMSMkdzUq4hEPmMihWHFWcchykyCrrmJuRE43lUWxiMVq8ZyNyJkzEAIZG%2B4IJhtEixCSkUHrSSwnJBSSlTKqUHI2zSEJtK6UWFoicRkTJmQ2izGydlXjkuZrmNmPMMhiJYNzZEGR40NqGR7SVR5xYgDJqFKWMs5bwSLu/IG5NyIqyIGrRmGsLza2BKFdZEIDZG0gbmU25tLbA32veW29sfpO0EC7N2EQ12exNN7X2xxLABzEM0PuYcviRzah1f18cOqqFFMnVO46Z5z3%2BICPyYIl3L1OPVbqQID6MmAscKk941obQFgwU46rIo7WAw5I6XAToGL%2BVdPAN18P3SA4zBybrIaerhqgBGvc/UU3BMUNcSs0ahVCvRxjZgw1MRJFtOtERpJZUJE2xSyk22bQY/pzt3a9KfvHYzBi1bxJskirZ5iFsdMqcZfOhQxAfj9KyoM3tHKMoTnRkrRZh4pwzg0APNDrgH6AmrgkwIo6gRBobk9PYiEIheBmoqVQWTIqYb4bScjR8HpiznZ%2BMZqBaKiDGFIiB0oubvuXaxYGfbb1rjTf1QpBEyK%2BWlrLVALAaPrUbCCAgSzIouYY3TN8kUVOEgCwZOJoRDgIDepkPJq4fiRHXJnQlFghDP0VENBCyG1zMV7lWWITtaCOERA4EO1r%2ByHgRJuHGBAQ7IAYKUqVZy5X2MyIHLxXw84/HTRYKJABJNTNsFI/ohB9r7ikvDmyIBCWyRsLbDVar2qzLxKSz2s28JoHwtu/FwwvUES8YTLd3tiMjDIj5MDy9R9KxXPgfKpOhKmIdZBiB5KCCAzOCd49pN%2BpVq2SB4F54IfnMFN40GIGMIXTZIqxF4SLon7x%2BxdT3kCK9WsH5AwIGV/LqgLWSEkBai1a7z7m/5NsbYlvYwGW7QVIEnXLqiNk/Ub7rw8PG9UpSU%2BdJ2fORjaAiaaqzAQGN2LRb64DMtpUqWDkqcyxfrhxLxehGYRwgUAiL86IhdtdWV1AwRhoaRz16kEy8yAUKCBUCYAcKEAmS8DpScCB31eF3NPQn%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%2BD6MKZcHxSFBoxsTg%2BWRopQI4l4U4VAPAJw93YEx2TWS8B%2BVqGDAAKgQMVANwpLgipOIGpM82QFHxD1pGk1kSBDwDfHTwsD5O2DcAdDMEkAFL5MsGsA5PISK031nHKzbBonQC8DpRkR%2BgESfGpMWAgDZOsDwDPwOgch9gSAMFOiRllPw3BBMH5EFJtK5FoOIKhFIIAPILvmLyHAz0ZjPlHAQJtLtP5AdM6QQOdP/xQOJTQM9M5NA19LoP9L5MDMkjoNDOI2kgT013x2WJeA4GWFoE4H5F4D8A4C0FIFQE4DyKlMgyhLWCSh2B4FIAIE0BzOWDRBAEkC4DuCSEWkCEkApCSEkH8G3HbJ1DzI4EkELKbNLM4F4AUBAAVEbOLJzNIDgFgBgEQBQEG1cTIAoF3jzjoGGFENVVFA1jRD4DoEVVnIgFiEnNsiMkok4HrNvOaEojKliG0G%2BIfN4FzmDTKmVXvMXNICwGu2ADcE8VnO4F4CwBBCMHEAAvwFhgcDwHOHApLOXAuEBMnMBFqEnJ%2BDGWfI8CwEnK8JYE/OWFBSYGAAUFxFcl3DKg6iLPrP4EEBEDEHYHoSYvkCUDUEnN0GVFUJQGsGsH0G8NnNgGYDYBAFOH2FIGyk4DSR4F7VLNSF93AqsjKm2EOBxXWEeE5B1VRFwlkE0qKM8V4BNOMiJIKngGWDsG%2BOyBcFgkmD8GVDCF%2BHmGGGVBgIEEcr0E8oYDmCGESGVBssQoaHGFaE8HaD0GCt916BaH8oqHctsDCu8qCrCvioWCamrPWDYtzPzInIArLI4EOFUCCCsh7P0POlj0CQYDRCyQgFwEID%2BjrMWF4AXK0EUtbP5AVFHPHNIBIodAVCLJLMKpnLnIbKbOWBXKgDXIgCQBcX3O3MoHmoLhAEouYBeRljPNuwSEvOvIAqfOIH/MfNpkOtfPfIcE/NIG/Ibl/K8UnKAo71AqKnAvrKgoMNgpLPgtsuQsnLQvihGkwsEGwoAtwqGkOoIs2BLOItIr4AMEouoswFovosuo4pYvEHYtkAxW4oAt0A1H4tMErJsFwtEv8Jekkuktko4HkubKUpUs4DUo0q0tajfD0o2HLl6ismMqKlMuyipiwBJuspwhCr8F2QcoivyGctgnSsSt8pStIF8ulsCq6FstCr6Dluip6DStcoCqiuSvFqcqStmG1oSsCustWGyokFyo4ALNICGtMs4GKtKvKuADih%2BmPJqrqoavPQg2LBavGsXMUraiwESDbR6t4BIq6ttsnJGtsDGraqXKmtmo3L3ILnICWs3IWpQFoFhERohB7K2ovMoD2pLIOqOt4FLrOo/IgqusGx/L/PuswGAqetoBesgtwneshsgunG%2BssoAr%2BowoAqwtHJLNBvwowE7obKphIogrIrhqoporosYBRtkDRrYukA4qxvUBxpADVHxsEssGEtiBJogHEvYCktoBkuGCpvSRptQGUuyFUrKjlSsmaFahAGlWfoAHFvorIxh0ABLCaMkeaEg%2BbLLIBBbuhnBRb3B9a9AXKygdaPL8Dsg5aFbjaMrlbhbYrwq8gDaNbVa4r0HEqZgJhYHUqjaEGTbLaVgaycr9A8qo6CqHbVByqWAFApLZxElklJAfoijIcohsBPb8BvbmrWqJrlgg7hg21OrurOBeqI7Bro7pzY75zxHSAZH6GOBth8rhrlH46OqQB%2BR/A7gNAkgkhth%2BQ0lLl/ALH/ARy5Lw6JB4E7apyOAxGA6razAdH7a3H/b2rlhspMhnBJAgA) with a test loop ([uiCA](https://uica.uops.info/?code=%23%20clang%20-O3%20-march%3Dx86-64-v3%20-Wall%0D%0A%23%20maxpos_u8_noscan_unpack%20inlined%2C%20unrolled%20by%202%0D%0A.LBB5_1%3A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20%3D%3EThis%20Inner%20Loop%20Header%3A%20Depth%3D1%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20vmovdqu%20ymm3%2C%20ymmword%20ptr%20%5Brsi%20%2B%20rax%20-%201%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20vpunpcklbw%20%20%20%20%20%20ymm4%2C%20ymm0%2C%20ymm3%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20ymm4%20%3D%20ymm0%5B0%5D%2Cymm3%5B0%5D%2Cymm0%5B1%5D%2Cymm3%5B1%5D%2Cymm0%5B2%5D%2Cymm3%5B2%5D%2Cymm0%5B3%5D%2Cymm3%5B3%5D%2Cymm0%5B4%5D%2Cymm3%5B4%5D%2Cymm0%5B5%5D%2Cymm3%5B5%5D%2Cymm0%5B6%5D%2Cymm3%5B6%5D%2Cymm0%5B7%5D%2Cymm3%5B7%5D%2Cymm0%5B16%5D%2Cymm3%5B16%5D%2Cymm0%5B17%5D%2Cymm3%5B17%5D%2Cymm0%5B18%5D%2Cymm3%5B18%5D%2Cymm0%5B19%5D%2Cymm3%5B19%5D%2Cymm0%5B20%5D%2Cymm3%5B20%5D%2Cymm0%5B21%5D%2Cymm3%5B21%5D%2Cymm0%5B22%5D%2Cymm3%5B22%5D%2Cymm0%5B23%5D%2Cymm3%5B23%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20vpunpckhbw%20%20%20%20%20%20ymm3%2C%20ymm1%2C%20ymm3%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20ymm3%20%3D%20ymm1%5B8%5D%2Cymm3%5B8%5D%2Cymm1%5B9%5D%2Cymm3%5B9%5D%2Cymm1%5B10%5D%2Cymm3%5B10%5D%2Cymm1%5B11%5D%2Cymm3%5B11%5D%2Cymm1%5B12%5D%2Cymm3%5B12%5D%2Cymm1%5B13%5D%2Cymm3%5B13%5D%2Cymm1%5B14%5D%2Cymm3%5B14%5D%2Cymm1%5B15%5D%2Cymm3%5B15%5D%2Cymm1%5B24%5D%2Cymm3%5B24%5D%2Cymm1%5B25%5D%2Cymm3%5B25%5D%2Cymm1%5B26%5D%2Cymm3%5B26%5D%2Cymm1%5B27%5D%2Cymm3%5B27%5D%2Cymm1%5B28%5D%2Cymm3%5B28%5D%2Cymm1%5B29%5D%2Cymm3%5B29%5D%2Cymm1%5B30%5D%2Cymm3%5B30%5D%2Cymm1%5B31%5D%2Cymm3%5B31%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20vpmaxuw%20ymm3%2C%20ymm4%2C%20ymm3%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20vextracti128%20%20%20%20xmm4%2C%20ymm3%2C%201%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20vpmaxuw%20xmm3%2C%20xmm3%2C%20xmm4%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20vpxor%20%20%20xmm3%2C%20xmm3%2C%20xmm2%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20vphminposuw%20%20%20%20%20xmm3%2C%20xmm3%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20vpextrb%20byte%20ptr%20%5Brdi%20%2B%20rax%20-%201%5D%2C%20xmm3%2C%200%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20vmovdqu%20ymm3%2C%20ymmword%20ptr%20%5Brsi%20%2B%20rax%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20vpunpcklbw%20%20%20%20%20%20ymm4%2C%20ymm0%2C%20ymm3%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20ymm4%20%3D%20ymm0%5B0%5D%2Cymm3%5B0%5D%2Cymm0%5B1%5D%2Cymm3%5B1%5D%2Cymm0%5B2%5D%2Cymm3%5B2%5D%2Cymm0%5B3%5D%2Cymm3%5B3%5D%2Cymm0%5B4%5D%2Cymm3%5B4%5D%2Cymm0%5B5%5D%2Cymm3%5B5%5D%2Cymm0%5B6%5D%2Cymm3%5B6%5D%2Cymm0%5B7%5D%2Cymm3%5B7%5D%2Cymm0%5B16%5D%2Cymm3%5B16%5D%2Cymm0%5B17%5D%2Cymm3%5B17%5D%2Cymm0%5B18%5D%2Cymm3%5B18%5D%2Cymm0%5B19%5D%2Cymm3%5B19%5D%2Cymm0%5B20%5D%2Cymm3%5B20%5D%2Cymm0%5B21%5D%2Cymm3%5B21%5D%2Cymm0%5B22%5D%2Cymm3%5B22%5D%2Cymm0%5B23%5D%2Cymm3%5B23%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20vpunpckhbw%20%20%20%20%20%20ymm3%2C%20ymm1%2C%20ymm3%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20ymm3%20%3D%20ymm1%5B8%5D%2Cymm3%5B8%5D%2Cymm1%5B9%5D%2Cymm3%5B9%5D%2Cymm1%5B10%5D%2Cymm3%5B10%5D%2Cymm1%5B11%5D%2Cymm3%5B11%5D%2Cymm1%5B12%5D%2Cymm3%5B12%5D%2Cymm1%5B13%5D%2Cymm3%5B13%5D%2Cymm1%5B14%5D%2Cymm3%5B14%5D%2Cymm1%5B15%5D%2Cymm3%5B15%5D%2Cymm1%5B24%5D%2Cymm3%5B24%5D%2Cymm1%5B25%5D%2Cymm3%5B25%5D%2Cymm1%5B26%5D%2Cymm3%5B26%5D%2Cymm1%5B27%5D%2Cymm3%5B27%5D%2Cymm1%5B28%5D%2Cymm3%5B28%5D%2Cymm1%5B29%5D%2Cymm3%5B29%5D%2Cymm1%5B30%5D%2Cymm3%5B30%5D%2Cymm1%5B31%5D%2Cymm3%5B31%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20vpmaxuw%20ymm3%2C%20ymm4%2C%20ymm3%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20vextracti128%20%20%20%20xmm4%2C%20ymm3%2C%201%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20vpmaxuw%20xmm3%2C%20xmm3%2C%20xmm4%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20vpxor%20%20%20xmm3%2C%20xmm3%2C%20xmm2%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20vphminposuw%20%20%20%20%20xmm3%2C%20xmm3%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20vpextrb%20byte%20ptr%20%5Brdi%20%2B%20rax%5D%2C%20xmm3%2C%200%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20add%20%20%20%20%20rax%2C%202%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20cmp%20%20%20%20%20rax%2C%2010241%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20jne%20%20%20%20%20.LBB5_1&syntax=asIntel&uArchs=HSW&uArchs=SKL&uArchs=ICL&tools=uiCA&alignment=0)) to see how they inline and hoist constants, i.e. to get a loop I can copy/paste into https://uica.uops.info/
I was going to write the indices as normal numbers, and use `unpack(~indices, v)`.  But MSVC didn't constant-propagate through the bitwise not, doing it at run-time!

Clang is too clever for it's own good: it sees that some of the `indices` input elements aren't used by `_mm256_unpacklo_epi8` so it zeros them out.  Same for the unpack hi.  But that means it needs to load 2 different vector constants instead of having unpack read parts of the same one!  (TODO: report on https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/)

##### There are multiple strategies for unpacking:

- chtz's suggestions of `vpunpckl/hbw`, as above.  The in-lane behaviour is funky for 256-bit shuffles, but they do pair corresponding elements of the two input vectors.  This way needs fewer vector constants, just one non-trivial one except when clang pessimizes it, and fewer vector ALU uops, but more of them are shuffles, so on Skylake and earlier, port 5 could be a bottleneck depending on the surrounding code.  Not a problem as cleanup for you loop in [Why performance of this function is so slow on Intel i3-N305 compared to AMD Ryzen 7 3800X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77712908/why-performance-of-this-function-is-so-slow-on-intel-i3-n305-compared-to-amd-ryz) (where chtz's strategy could be expanded to your whole loop so the cleanup is just a `max` reduction of u16 elements, including the inversion for phminposuw.)

  Ice Lake and later, and Gracemont, can run `vpunpck` integer shuffles on more than one port so back-end port throughtput bottlenecks aren't a problem.
- Odd/even by shifting the even elements left to the top of a u16, and mask to isolate the odds.  (Then XOR to both flip the data and apply the index into the other half.)  Fewer of the uops are shifts, but 1 more total uop than unpack.  And more of the instructions are 256-bit YMM, worse on Zen 1 or your Gracemont.

  With AVX-512 (or AVX10 256-bit), `vpternlogd` is useful, but not much else.
- Compared to not using chtz's trick at all, using bcast/cmp/movemask/scan: no vector constants needed at all. Perhaps good as a one-off, like cleanup for an infrequently-run loop.  It's 10 uops to get a scalar integer result (starting from data in a YMM vector) vs. 9 for vpunpckl/hbw on an Intel P-core.   (7 uops for that to get the index in the bottom byte of an XMM register, or 8 total (including a `vpand` or `vpmovzxbq`) to get it zero-extended into a qword at the bottom, where you could `vpaddd` or `vpaddq` to accumulate it into an XMM total which you retrieve after your outer loop.)

##### shift/XOR strategy, fewer shuffles but more uops and constants, possible use-cases on Skylake

```
int maxpos_u8_noscan_odd_even(const Vec32uc v)
{
    // 0,2,4... unpacked with FF bytes
    __m256i indices_even = _mm256_setr_epi16(
        0xff00, 0xff02, 0xff04, 0xff06, 0xff08, 0xff0a, 0xff0c, 0xff0e,
        0xff10, 0xff12, 0xff14, 0xff16, 0xff18, 0xff1a, 0xff1c, 0xff1e);
    __m256i indices_odd = _mm256_sub_epi16(indices_even, _mm256_set1_epi16(-1));  // save typing, and it wouldn't be too bad if the compiler actually did it at runtime this way.  MSVC 19.14 (2017) actually does!
    // _mm256_setr_epi16(0xff01, 0xff03, ...

    __m256i even = _mm256_slli_epi16(v, 8);          // bring values to the top of each u16
    even = _mm256_xor_si256(even, indices_even);     // AVX-512: merge-masked vpshufb?  But that doesn't flip the data.  Do that separately? Use merge-masked sub for odds?
    __m256i odd = _mm256_and_si256(v, _mm256_set1_epi16(0xff00));
    odd = _mm256_xor_si256(odd, indices_odd);     // AVX-512 _mm256_ternlog_epi32 would be great
// NOT the data (255-v) while we unpack with indices; now we're looking for the min element
    
    Vec16us vu16 = _mm256_min_epu16(odd, even);    // values are the "key", and bring the index along with
    Vec8us vu8 = min(vu16.get_low(), vu16.get_high());  // narrow to 128-bit

    __m128i minpos = _mm_minpos_epu16(vu8);  // value:index in the bottom two bytes of the vector
    unsigned min = _mm_cvtsi128_si32(minpos);
    return (uint8_t)min;                      // movd + scalar movzx is cheaper than  pextrb 0
}
```

---

#### Earlier version, with bcast / cmp / movemask / tzcnt cleanup

```
int maxpos_u8(const Vec32uc v)
{
    auto vinv32 = ~v;   // 1:1 mapping that flips max to min
       // now we're looking for minpos_u8(vinv32).
    Vec16uc vinv = min(vinv32.get_low(), vinv32.get_high());
       // Reduce to 8x u16
    Vec8us vus = Vec8us(min(vinv, _mm_srli_epi16(vinv, 8)));
    // min of each pair 0-extended into a 16-bit element, since minu(0, x) = 0 in high half

    Vec32uc minval = _mm256_broadcastb_epi8(_mm_minpos_epu16(vus));  // bottom u16 is the min value, second u16 is the min pos
    auto match = (minval == vinv32);
    return _tzcnt_u32(_mm256_movemask_epi8(match));
 // VCL has silly inline asm for BSF.
 // Use __builtin_ctz, std::countr_zero, or a portable tzcnt intrinsic since we have AVX2
}
```

AVX2 basically implies BMI1/2, so requiring it for `tzcnt` too won't exclude any AVX2 CPUs.  Compile with GCC/Clang -march=x86-64-v3 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Microarchitecture_levels) or MSVC -arch:AVX2 which actually implies BMI2 as well.  Or use `std::countr_zero` from C++20 `#include <bit>`, but make sure to enable BMI so compilers can use `tzcnt`.

I changed the arg type to take a vector by value (in a YMM register).  This means the non-inline version needs to shuffle instead of loading the 128-bit halves separately to reduce to 128.  This is generally a good convention since callers might pass vectors that aren't already in memory, although you want small functions like this to inline.

[**Godbolt**](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:22,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:22,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:22,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:22),source:%27%23include+%22vectorclass.h%22%0A%0Aint+maxpos_u8(const+Vec32uc+v)+%7B%0A++++auto+vinv32+%3D+%7Ev%3B+++//+1:1+mapping+that+flips+max+to+min%0A++++//+now+we!%27re+looking+for+the+position+of+the+min+in+vinv32%0A++++Vec16uc+vinv+%3D+min(vinv32.get_low(),+vinv32.get_high())%3B%0A%0A++++Vec8us+vus+%3D+Vec8us(min(vinv,+_mm_srli_epi16(vinv,+8)))%3B%0A++++//+min+of+each+pair+0-extended+into+a+16-bit+element,+since+minu(0,+x)+%3D+0%0A++++Vec32uc+minval+%3D+_mm256_broadcastb_epi8(_mm_minpos_epu16(vus))%3B++//+min+value+goes+at+the+bottom%0A++++auto+match+%3D+(minval+%3D%3D+vinv32)%3B%0A++++//+VCL+has+silly+inline+asm+for+BSF,+rather+than+using+__builtin_ctz+which+can+use+tzcn%0A++++//+AVX2+basically+implies+BMI2%0A++++return+_tzcnt_u32(_mm256_movemask_epi8(match))%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0Aint+maxpos_u8_VCL(const+Vec32uc+a)+%7B%0A++Vec32uc+b%7Bhorizontal_max(a)%7D%3B%0A++return+horizontal_find_first(a+%3D%3D+b)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+test()%7B%0A++++__m256i+a+%3D+_mm256_set1_epi32(0x33445521)%3B%0A++++return+maxpos_u8(a)%3B++//+even+clang!%27s+constprop+doesn!%27t+go+through+phminposuw%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()%7B%0A++++__m256i+a+%3D+_mm256_set1_epi32(0x33445521)%3B%0A++++//return+maxpos_u8(a)%3B++//+return+the+actual+position%0A++++return+maxpos_u8(a)+!!%3D+maxpos_u8_VCL(a)%3B+++//+return+0+on+success%0A%7D%0A%0A%0A%23ifdef+__clang__%0Aint+test_asm()%7B%0A++++int+ver+%3D+__clang_major__%3B++++//+17+with+clang+17+as+expected%0A++++//+instrset.h+is+supposed+to+only+use+__attribute__((noinline))+for+__clang_major__+%3C+10%0A++++//return+ver+%2B+bit_scan_forward(1UL%3C%3C0)%3B%0A++++//+We+don!%27t+want+inline+asm+at+all,+though,+we+want+tzcnt+that!%27s+not+slow+on+AMD%0A++++return+ver+%2B+__builtin_ctz(1UL%3C%3C0)%3B%0A%7D%0A%23endif%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:43.11217114773056,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g132,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!((name:vcl,ver:%27201%27)),options:%27-O3+-march%3Dalderlake+-Wall%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:14,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:14,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:13,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:13),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+13.2+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:27.664629099391302,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang1701,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!((name:vcl,ver:%27201%27)),options:%27-O3+-march%3Dalderlake+-Wall%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:12,endLineNumber:13,positionColumn:12,positionLineNumber:13,selectionStartColumn:12,selectionStartLineNumber:13,startColumn:12,startLineNumber:13),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+clang+17.0.1+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.33333333333333,l:%274%27,m:58.684480986639265,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+clang+17.0.1%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+clang+17.0.1+(Compiler+%232)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:41.315519013360735,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:29.223199752878138,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

```
# clang and GCC make identical asm, except clang spends a vzeroupper when not inlining.
maxpos_u8(Vec32uc):
           vpcmpeqd        ymm1, ymm1, ymm1     # all-ones mask, can be hoisted from loops
        vpxor   ymm0, ymm0, ymm1             # NOT = xor(v, -1)
        vextracti128    xmm2, ymm0, 0x1      # same first shuffle step
        vpminub xmm1, xmm0, xmm2

        vpsrlw  xmm2, xmm1, 8                # 16-bit element size shifts in zeros
        vpminub xmm1, xmm1, xmm2
        vphminposuw     xmm1, xmm1

        vpbroadcastb    ymm1, xmm1           # then same cleanup
        vpcmpeqb        ymm0, ymm0, ymm1
        vpmovmskb       eax, ymm0
        tzcnt   eax, eax
        ret
```

According to https://uica.uops.info/, it's 10 uops for the front-end on Skylake (not counting the `vpcmpeqd` ones idiom that can be hoisted out of loops, and not counting the `ret`.)  vs. the VCL version (using `tzcnt` instead of branch around bsf) being 14 uops.

It has 15 cycle latency from input to the final `ymm0` result.  (Plus another maybe 4 or 6 cycles for movemask + tzcnt, which is the same for both versions if we improve the VCL cleanup, or even with `bsf` on Intel.)
The VCL version is 16 cycle latency from ymm0 input to `vpcmpeqb` result, so **my version is better by 1 cycle for latency**.  (Probably by 2 cycles on Zen-family, where `phminposuw` is only 3c latency instead of 4 on Intel.)

My version is 10 uops (not counting `vpcmpeqd`, assuming it was hoisted out of a loop) vs. 14 for the VCL version (assuming it's changed to use `tzcnt`).

6 of the uops for the VCL version can only run on port 5 on Skylake, so a loop doing *only* this would bottleneck on that for throughput.  On Ice Lake they're fairly evenly distributed since the shuffles can run on port 1 or 5.

Machine-code size for my version is smaller by 13 bytes (counting the `vpcmpeqd` `set1(-1)` since it's part of static code size); smaller is generally good for I-cache density.  (The VCL shuffles could have avoided immediate operands for some, saving a couple bytes.)

---

This worked out better than I thought it might.  I was worried we were going to have to invert again after `phminposuw` to recover the actual max element, but matching against the transformed `vinv32` avoids that.  (If you *do* want the value as well, `uint8_t min = ~_mm_cvtsi128_si32(minpos_result);` - `movd` + `not`, and maybe a `movzx` if you need it as 32-bit.)  And `phminposuw` leaves the value at the bottom of the register, position above that, so a broadcast to 256 worked without an extra shift or shuffle.

Also, at first I though we might need an AND or something to zero-extend to 16-bit, or that I'd have to shift left so the value we wanted was in most-significant half of the u16 elements (so low garbage wouldn't matter).  But again, then we'd have needed to broadcast a byte that wasn't the lowest, which would have required a shift + vpbroadcast, or AVX-512 `vpermb`.

---

#### VCL uses `bsf`!?!?

**The most obvious thing to improve on is VCL's [insane use of inline `asm`](https://github.com/vectorclass/version2/blob/f4617df57e17efcd754f5bbe0ec87883e0ed9ce6/instrset.h#L275)** for a legacy BSF instruction (slow on AMD), instead of using GNU C `__builtin_ctz` on non-MSVC.  That can compile to `tzcnt` on CPUs that have it (all CPUs with AVX2 have BMI1/2). Even on CPUs that *don't* have it, since unlike `lzcnt`, the `tzcnt` result is compatible with `bsf` for all cases where `__builtin_ctz` has a well-defined result (when the input is non-zero), and `tzcnt`=`rep bsf` which runs as `bsf` on older CPUs.  (There's some possible justification for using inline asm for `bsr` in `bit_scan_reverse`, but probably still better to use `63-` or `31 - __builtin_clz` there.)

And we know there will be a match, so `horizontal_find_first`'s `if (bits == 0) return -1;` is totally useless even if we were using `bsf` instead of `tzcnt`.  (`tzcnt` produces `32` or `64` in that case, the operand-size.)

---

##### Avoiding the broadcast: stay 256-bit the whole time?

This isn't better for u8 or u16 elements.  (Also, chtz's idea of unpacking with indices made it a moot point.)

**If you weren't using `vphminposuw`, you might avoid the `vpbroadcastb` by doing all your shuffles at 256-bit**, so you finish with the max already broadcast.  e.g. `vpermi128` instead of `vextracti128`.  But I'm not sure how you swap bytes within words or dwords without needing a control vector for `vpshufb`.  Perhaps `vpalignr ymm, same,same, imm8` with 8 / 4 / 2 / 1?  It's port 5 only even on Ice Lake, and higher latency (2 cycles) on Zen 4 vs. `vpshufd`.  And the first two shuffles (by 8 and 4) can be done with `vpshufd` which can run on more port 1 or 5 on Ice Lake and later, for better balance of uops for execution ports, which is generally good unless the surrounding code under-uses port 5.

But this strategy is worse for throughput on Zen 1 and Alder Lake E-cores (Gracemont), since all the 256-bit ops will be 2 uops.  They're wide enough that it's ok for latency, you don't get resource conflicts.

Comment: I think you could avoid the pbroadcastb/pcmpeqb/pmovmsk/tzcnt, if you interleave the values with their indexes before finding the minimum. I haven't checked if it is actually better. Maybe I work out a full solution, if I'm bored the next days ...

Comment: @chtz: Oh, with value in the high byte, index in the low byte, so a `_mm256_min_epu16` reduction from 32x u8 to 16x u16 (via 2x32 u16 shift / AND + OR) takes the min value and brings the index with it.  Same for `phminposuw`.  Yeah, great idea.  Needs some vector constants, but should be better in a loop.  And even if we have to load 3x 32-byte constants for AND and indices for odd/even elements, should be better for latency especially on Intel (Zen has 1c latency tzcnt and vpbroadcastb ymm).  And maybe better back-end throughput. For front-end throughput, the loads can micro-fuse if used once

Comment: @chtz: With the right constants (0xff00, 0xff02, etc) we can even combine inversion (`NOT` or `255-v`) with setting indices, like `_mm256_sub_epu8(const, v)`.  That doesn't allow a memory-source constant for the non-looping case, though.  Oh, or we can `_mm256_xor_epu8(v, const)` if we've already zeroed the low byte of each, with the same `..., 0xff02, ...` constant.  It's tempting to want to use those high 0xFF bytes as the AND mask to avoid needing a third mask for the odd elements.  An AVX512 merge-masked `vpsubb` could do it.  (There is no `vpxorb`)

Comment: You'd just need one additional constant with `{0, 1, ..., 31}` and interleave that with `vpunpcklbw` and `vpunpckhbw` (as you reduce everything to a single `__m128i` the weird order of these does not matter).

Comment: @chtz: Oh yeah, cool.  And you can reduce with `max` until you get to a single `__m128i`,  NOTing at at that point so you only need a 128-bit `pxor`, saving a uop on Alder Lake E-cores.  (But your indices have to be ~0, ~1, ~2, etc.)  So it costs 2x 256-bit vpunppck instructions (p15 on Ice Lake, find on E-cores, and cheap on AMD) and a 128-bit vpxor.  vs. my idea costing 4x 256-bit instructions, but no shuffles: `vpsllw` + `vpxor` (even elements) and `vpand` + `vpxor` (odd elements)

Comment: @chtz: I implemented your ideas.  The unpack one is the most compact, a uop smaller than my shift/xor idea.